# Saving post meta

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, save-post

I'm not sure why my meta data isn't saving on 'save draft'. When I click save draft the data disappears. I think I've got it all right. I've run the code in the validator and all appears fine?

```
function fhaac_save_rubric_meta( $post_id ){
     //Checking save status
  $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
  $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
  $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'fhacc_rubric_nounce' ]) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'fhacc_rubric_nounce' ], basename(__FILE__ 
 )))?'true' : 'false';

   //Exit scripts depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce){
    return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST['criteria'])){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'criteria', sanitize_text_field($_POST['criteria']));
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'fhaac_save_rubric_meta');
```

Any help would be really useful and greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried your function and it worked fine!
Can you add here your render meta box function?

Comment: Are you using `get_post_meta()` on your meta box to display the values? Can you verify in DB whether meta is not/is saved?

Comment: Sorry guys, thanks for your replies... Idiot = me. I forgot to add criteria as the key to the fields. Thanks for your help anyway